# Postfix: "Relay Access Denied"

Tags: linux, email, debian, postfix

I've been following this tutorial: http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/index.html

For some reason, even after making sure that I set it up correctly, it will not send any mail to external domains. It can still receive from them, but sending results in this:

```
postfix/smtpd[26338]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 554 5.7.1 <xxxx@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<user@domain.com> to=<xxxx@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<domain.com>
```

I've got TLS enabled, as well as amavis. Disabling either (or both) doesn't change anything. I can also send to my own domain, and it will arrive correctly.

Here's my /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
myorigin = domain.com
masquerade_domains = mail.domain.com
masquerade_exceptions = root

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/postfix.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/postfix.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtp_tls_security_level = may

smtpd_tls_security_level = may

smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes

smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mail.domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = mail.domain.com
mydestination = domain.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104, [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
mynetworks_style = host

local_recipient_maps =
mydestination =
delay_warning_time = 4h
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
maximum_queue_lifetime = 7d
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s

smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtpd_recipient_limit = 32
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12

smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname,  reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining

smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes

alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases

virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf

virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf

virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf

virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000

content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

# SASL
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = domain.com
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `reject_unauth_destination` from `smtpd_client_restrictions`.

**EDIT**

You are using **SMTP** to send email, so `postfix` still uses all `smtpd_*_restrictions` even though you are connecting from `127.0.0.1`. These `smtpd_*_restrictions` are applied in following [order](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#timing): client, helo, sender, recipient, data, or end-of-data. [`reject_unauth_destination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unauth_destination) rejects any mail unless domain in **RCPT TO** matches `$mydestionation` or `$relay_domains`. In your case, when `reject_unauth_destination` is used in `smtpd_client_restrictions`, which is checked first, your mail almost immediately (after checking two RBLs) gets rejected because your `postfix` obviously isn't final destination for gmail.com and all rules to allow relaying mail from local or authenticated clients (`permit_mynetworks`, `permit_sasl_authenticated`) are [skipped](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#timing) because you are already got REJECT from `smtpd_client_restrictions`.

Comment: And then you have to authenticate by SMTP-AUTH to be able to relay mails.

Comment: @mailq could you explain that a little bit more?

Comment: His log message doesn't match the configuration. If he really sends from 127.0.0.1 there shouldn't be a relay problem as it is allowed by permit_mynetworks. But if he sends from "outside" he must SMTP-AUTH to get past permit_sasl_authenticated.

Comment: @mailq I've added more detailed explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! This actually fixed it, and now I can send to external domains.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, I sortered all smtpd_client_restrictions and my configuration works

This is a configuration should works:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
check_policy_service unix:/var/spool/postfix/postgrey/socket,
reject_rbl_client xbl.spamhaus.org,
reject_rbl_client pbl.spamhaus.org,
reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
reject_rbl_client multi.uribl.com,
reject_rbl_client rbl-plus.mail-abuse.org,
reject_rbl_client dialups.mail-abuse.org,
permit_mynetworks,
reject_unauth_destination,
reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
reject_unknown_sender_domain,
reject_unknown_recipient_domain
```

Sorting is important.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, this saved me:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, 
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unauth_destination
```

Answer (score -1):

You must configure your server for relaying.

Try to add an external smtp host for the option relayhost:

```
postconf -e 'relayhost = smtp.example.com'
```